# Typescript function overload depending on interface generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to declare a method overload with an optional parameter if a class generic is of a certain type? In the below example the goal is to have a class whose `run` method requires an argument only if the class's generic `T` is a number. What I've written doesn't work: I think the `T` in the `run` declaration is interpreted as a different generic than `Test`'s generic `T`. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
class Test<T extends string | number> {
  run<T extends number>(a: number): void
  run<T extends string>(a?: number): void
  run(a: number): void {
    console.log(a)
  }
}

const a = new Test<number>();
a.run() // This should be an error, as a's generic is a number and thus its run method should require an argument.

const b = new Test<string>();
b.run() // OK, since b's generic is a string.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [conditionally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) is a useful choice for your method in this case:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=16&ssc=15&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0A8trwB5PgOwBMZkAnASzwHNoAfaPAVwFsAjeEgPmgG8AoaaCQZ5oACgB0ksCUoQAXHEw58ReszYloAfmgBtMAsat2AXWgL9Ww+tMBKBQDcA9mQI9+A6MCd5kesGYAvNDSsgDcHgLevk4g8OIgTpSiYLZh0AD0GWrGmnTCBPAAZhTwBB4AvrxVvNF+YNDBePAA7nCISKhGGhyiabxg4kJ4ogAsAExpmdlOANYDQ8J96RkAVB4AeltbvACiWAAO8MC4bgCMITLM+EgQADTQLAwolE4oAAziouMArD+jtmgqwyvFqPj8LEa9Fa7WQqFIFEovX6LEWIwmUyy0DmvFRw2W02xsyAA)

```ts
class Test <T extends string | number> {
  run (...args: T extends number ? [a: number] : [a?: number]): void {
    const [a] = args;
    console.log(a); // number | undefined
  }
}

const a = new Test<number>();
a.run(42); // ok
a.run(); /*
  ^^^^^
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.(2554) */

const b = new Test<string>();
b.run(42); // ok
b.run(); // ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find a way to accomplish this using only one classes, but i'm not sure it's possible. It makes sense, since having the same function called in a different way is not very *clean*.

What you could do, is use an interface, a parent class and multiple child class. This would allow you to use one or the other, and stay *DRY* at the same time. Here is my take on this problem.

```js
// we create an interface with an optional parameter "a"
interface ITest {
  run(a?: number) : void;
}

// we create a super class that will handle the process of the "run" function.
// this class has a function with a necessary parameter
abstract class AbstractTest<T extends string|number> {
  run(a: T) {
    console.log('ran with param: ', a);
  }
}

// We create two sub class, one for the run with no parameter, one with the run with one parameter. 
// Both classes implements the interface and calls the parent function "run".

// this class does not extends the "run" function, since it is the same as the parent one
class TestNumber<T extends number> extends AbstractTest<T> implements ITest {}

// this class extends the "run" function, since it needs to process the fact that there is no parameters passsed
// to the "run" function. I've used a default value here, but it will depend on your use case.
class TestString<T extends string> extends AbstractTest<T> implements ITest {
  public static readonly DEFAULT_VALUE = 'some value';

  run() : void {
    super.run(TestString.DEFAULT_VALUE as T)
  }
}

// we create new objects based on the need.
const a = new TestNumber<number>();
const b = new TestString<string>();

// this function call works since we've passed a parameter
a.run(42);
// this one does not work and an error is thrown.
a.run()

// this function call works great without an argument.
b.run()
```

I've placed comments to explain the changes. [here is a typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-jddPiVeuKcdVRtduYkej0FjY0ggeQPPyEyDUhUiTXZQQcbMPLmfDw8U4cUUc9dVJFI9DA3tspksMc0G0J9coVckEI2lYKkcbG00E3kBYpY2gqLGpCpKAb6RMazCgFMNDaKyT6BLEkDNJm8TZgAynsDxFoOgZ3Og9yViWQ6gDsqxEAcnYNuqmqQNqbayNmnyaHQNKsFgMBhMgKDcVoSBeugrAzAAIgAogAYlsACqAAycgAPoAGpbPJskSaAAC8oCwmCSY-qwf6wriop6PYTguC+gJAuEkQypUejYbhxGNJJMkKcpakaVpsSgP8Xz4r4-hQLAZIhGM4C0JYABW4zMZYqEvrBIqzq46GgiofS6VFAWdnmryFuW7wWZ4rrkO0Y6DCaEGUnAADWtxTgE965KqL59Ly+6LIgjROQALAATDiFVVRKXo+kqVDGtQNj5KyVUUPk4DoM0fVObYvgZlloC0rlkDRS5cB4URJFlWN8RhuOmAwKaEAsk1oD3BFQoIdlmBcPcFits0lj9T8thAA) with the working code